# kdevelop to use ctags

Tags: c++, ctags, kdevelop

I am having KDevelop version 4.3.1 on my ubuntu box. I want the editor to use the ctags file generated manually. It does not detect tag file located at ~/projects/project_name/tags.

How do i make KDevelop use the ctags file ? Any answers/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop doesn't support ctags, instead KDevelop tries to understand much better than ctags does.

It would be possible though to implement a ctags plugin for KDevelop.